# c++ Boost creating IP address using from_string results in lambda error

Tags: c++, boost, lambda

I have a main function that parses flagged arguments. One of these is an IP Address string (v4). I save the value in a char array.

I then move the char array to a const string.

```
const std::string &str(ip_address);
```

After some validation checks, I want to set this IP address to be used by my code.

```
boost::asio::ip::address a = boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(str);
```

However, this line results in the error (intellisense):

> An enclosing-function local variable cannot be referenced in a lambda
>   body unless it is in the capture list

And a compile error:

> Error C3493: 'str' cannot be implicitly captured because no
>   default capture mode has been specified

How can I set the IP Address without hard coding it?

Note: I have 2 network adapters, I need the program to run on each and I am passing the IP address of each.

EDIT: (full code section)

```
CLASS::Main(int argc, char **argv)
    : io_service(nullptr), server(nullptr), iso_parameters(nullptr), wcs_connection(nullptr), class_protocol(nullptr)
{
    char c;
    char ip_address[20];
    //set_warehouse_argument(argc, argv);
    while( -1 != (c = getopt(argc,argv,"w:i:a:")) )
    {
        switch(c)
        {
            case 'i':
                mydat.instance = atoi(optarg);
                break;
            case 'w':
                /* Processed by set_warehouse_argument */
                break;
            case 'a':
                strcpy_s(ip_address, optarg);
                break;
            default:
                usage(argv[0],"Invalid argument flag passed.");
                exit(1);
        }
    }

    const std::string &str(ip_address);

    if(mydat.instance <= 0 || mydat.instance > 5)
    {
        usage(argv[0],"Invalid or missing instance passed (valid is 1-5).");
        exit(1);
    }

    accept_handler = [this](boost::shared_ptr<iso::connection>& socket, const boost::system::error_code& error) 
    {
        if(error != 0)
        {
            LOG_ERROR(mydat.instance) << "Error on accept: " << error.message();
        }
        else
        {
            /* Kick out the old client if present */
            if(wcs_connection && wcs_connection->state() != tcp_connection::DISCONNECTED)
            {
                LOG_EVENT << "New connection. Closing old client.";
                wcs_connection->close();
            }

            /* Initialize the connection and log the IP address */
            pending_connection = socket;
            auto now = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
            this->connection_timeout = now;

            boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket &s = pending_connection->socket(); 
            boost::system::error_code ec; 
            boost::asio::ip::address a = boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(str);
            if(ec == 0)
            {
                LOG_EVENT << "Client (socket " << s.native_handle() << ") from " << a.to_string() << " connected.";
            }
            else
            {
                LOG_ERROR(mydat.instance) << "Error on looking up remote endpoint for new client: " << ec.message();
                pending_connection->close();
                pending_connection = nullptr;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: The code as shown has no `lambda`.  Please edit your question to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: That is part of my problem; I'm getting lambda related errors and I have not coded a lambda. I think it is down in the boost libraries somewhere, but have not been able to find it.

Comment: I tested your code piece with gcc and boost 1.66 and it's working fine. Can you show all the code? Maybe the error is somewhere elese. BTW, `address::from_string` has been deprecated, it's recommended to use `ip::make_address_v4` or `ip::make_address_v6` now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm getting lambda related errors and I have not coded a lambda.

You most certainly *have* coded a `lambda` -- `accept_handler`, but you haven't captured `str`.  Change it to...

```
accept_handler = [this, str](boost::shared_ptr<iso::connection>& socket,
                             const boost::system::error_code& error)
```

Having said that, you don't actually show the declaration of `accept_handler` so I'm still guessing slightly that this is the source of the problem.